# Problem setting up custom URL Protocol on Windows CE

Tags: windows-mobile, registry, url-protocol

I am trying to setup a custom URL Protocol (testProtocol) on a Windows CE device.  When the user clicks a link with testProtocol it will launch an application (ParamTest.exe).

I have done the following:

Created a Windows Smart Device Project -> Device Application.

I altered the Main() method to take in a string[] of arguments which will be passed along with the Protocol:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{ }
```

Since this is a test all that this application does is pass the args to a form which displays the arguments.

Next I've setup the following registry entries on the handset:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
  Software
    Microsoft
      Shell
        URLProtocols
          testProtocol
```

and

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
  testProtocol
    (Default) = "URL:Test Protocol"
    URL Protocol = ""
      Shell
        Open
          Command
            (Default) = "\Program Files\ParamTest\ParamTest.exe" "%1"
```

Whenever I navigate to testProtocol:12345 or testProtocol://54321 I get the following error:

> "There is no application associated
>   with "testProtocol:12345".  Run the
>   application first, then open this file
>   from within the application."

I can run the application by navigating to \Program Files\ParamTest\ParamTest.exe.  I made a cab file to install the file and make all registry entries, i've verified that these are correct using the CERegEditor tool.

Do have have to set a permission/mime-type/extra registry entry?  Any help appreciated as this is driving me mad!

The OS version on the system i'm running the application on is 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where your error is, from the layout of your registry settings, maybe your `Shell` subkey is one in the wrong position?

Here is how it works for me:

First creating the following registry keys and values:

```
[HKCR\testProtocol]
URL Protocol=""

[HKCR\testProtocol\Shell\Open\Command]
@=""\Program Files\ParamTest\ParamTest.exe" "%1""

[HKLM\software\microsoft\shell\urlprotocols\testProtocol]
```

Then creating a test html file:

```
<a href="testProtocol:12345">open 12345</a>
```

Then opening this file in internet explorer on my device, the ParamTest program is called with argument `testprotocol:12345`